# SubscibeOn has no effect on Subjects

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rx-java2

As per my understanding,

- The `SubscribeOn` operator specifies the Thread in which the
  Observable source should start emission.
- If you have multiple `SubscribeOn` on a chain, the first one takes
  effect for the entire flow.
- `ObserveOn` can be used to flip the Thread to the downstream at any
  point, Whenever an `ObserveOn` present in a chain, it changes the
  thread for the downstream

But I tried a sample with `Subject` and I can see theres no effect for `SubscribeOn` in the entire chain.

Here's my sample

```
    Subject<String> mSubject = PublishSubject.create();
```

I consume it like

```
             mSubject
            .map(s -> "String :" + s)
            .doOnNext(s -> Log.d(TAG, "Started at Thread :" + Thread.currentThread().getName()))
            .flatMap(s -> Observable.just(1))
            .map(Object::toString)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(s -> {
                Log.d(TAG, "subscribed: " + s + " at " + Thread.currentThread().getName());

            });
```

and trigger from some other place

```
            mSubject.onNext("hello");
```

Here you can see, I have given `.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())`  , So I expect

```
             mSubject
            .map(s -> "String :" + s)
            .doOnNext(s -> Log.d(TAG, "Started at Thread :" + Thread.currentThread().getName()))
            .flatMap(s -> Observable.just(1))
            .map(Object::toString)
```

till these to execute in a Scheduler Thread. Then I flip the thread Using `observeOn` to the main thread. But here the log for this code

```
              D/MainActivity: Started at Thread :main
              D/MainActivity: subscribed: 1 at main
```

Why didn't it start on Scheduler thread?

The same I tried using normal `Observable` without using a subject.

```
             Observable.just("Hello")
            .map(s -> "String :" + s)
            .doOnNext(s -> Log.d(TAG, "Started at Thread :" + Thread.currentThread().getName()))
            .flatMap(s -> Observable.just(1))
            .map(Object::toString)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(s -> {
                Log.d(TAG, "subscribed: " + s + " at " + Thread.currentThread().getName());

            });
```

and here's the log

```
             D/MainActivity: Started at Thread :RxCachedThreadScheduler-2
             D/MainActivity: subscribed: 1 at main
```

I can see it is working as expected!

So what happened with the subjects

Comment: Subjects have no subscription side-effects and the thread where `Subject.onNext` is called on will be the thread where the Observers receive the values. Also you can read this: http://akarnokd.blogspot.hu/2017/11/when-multiple-subscribeons-do-have.html

Comment: @akarnokd nice read, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

From the post [Using subjects](https://xgrommx.github.io/rx-book/content/getting_started_with_rxjs/subjects.html) (which is linked by the official RxJava [Subject](http://reactivex.io/documentation/subject.html) documentation), it states:

> By default, subjects do not perform any synchronization across threads. They do not take a scheduler but rather assume that all serialization and grammatical correctness are handled by the caller of the subject.

So, to my best understanding this means that the thread used is the one of the code calling the `onNext()`, and later is sent to the observed thread.

Comment: I've just noticed that the document I linked is for RxJS... but makes sense for RxJava (even more than for Javascript, as *usually* no threads are used there).